# How can I ask the system which kind of regex less is using?

Tags: less

In every Unix like OS for the utility less, I cannot figure out which kind of regular expressions is to be used .in reality. The manual says only "as recognized by the regular expression library supplied by your system".

On my system Kubuntu, e.g., when applying grep, I can choose the kind of regex. It is necessary to either set options to reliably specify, or to query the system.

Such knowledge is not only good  when I am typing to save time, especially it is important to query in scripts and accordingly control the flow.

Answer (score 2):

You don't ask the system ... You ask `less` like so:

```
$ less --version
less 590 (GNU regular expressions) <------ THIS
Copyright (C) 1984-2021  Mark Nudelman

less comes with NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
For information about the terms of redistribution,
see the file named README in the less distribution.
Home page: https://greenwoodsoftware.com/less
```

Comment: As an additional data point, on Arch Linux it says "less 590 (PCRE2 regular expressions)"

Answer (score 0):

On a POSIX based system, it should be using `regcomp()` and `regexec()`, i.e. BRE/ERE.